# How to speed up IntelliJ on checking out Git branches?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.1 for working with Java projects, which are managed with Git. These are really big projects, and when I check out a branch using IntelliJ's Git integration, the check-out procedure sometimes stucks at "Indexing..." which then makes IntelliJ freeze and it takes atleast a minute to continue/unfreeze. So my question is, how I could speed up that "indexing..." process from Git checkout?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to invalidate the caches?

Just press Ctrl + Shift + a an type in "invalidate caches/restart".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that didn't solve the problem, maybe just temporary.